# Postgres, Supabase and Math

Tags: postgresql, supabase

I am new to Supabase and I know it uses Postgres. I have database containing 2 tables (for now):

1. meals
2. days of diet

meals contain:
name, photo, calories, protein, carbs etc.

days of diet contain:
array with meals id, total calories, total proteins, total carbs etc.

Can I set Postgres to do the math for me? Something like:

day of diet calories: sum all calories of array with meals

Also, since I can't have foreign key array it would have to be something like:

day of diet calories: for each (get meal with id) calories sum it up

Thank you for answering - I know doing it first method is possible but I don't think it's the best way. Hope you have a great day.

I can use my "backend" to add meal to day of diet, take "total calories" and add new meal calories to it. It is working great BUT what if I edit meal? I change calories? Then day of diet is wrong. I could code my backend to "refresh" data of every day of diet containing edited meal but it seems like a slow approach.

Comment: Never store arrays of IDs. Use a junction table for m-to-n relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I almost finished this with Postgres Functions and Triggers :P Going well, will post an answer once I finish.

```html
BEGIN
  UPDATE ingredient
  SET iname = NEW.iname,
      calories = NEW.calories_per_100 * ingredient.grams / 100,
      protein = NEW.protein_per_100 * ingredient.grams / 100,
      carbs = NEW.carbs_per_100 * ingredient.grams / 100,
      typ = NEW.typ
  WHERE ingredient = NEW.id;
  
  RETURN NEW;
END
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).